# Multi-label Image Classification along with the label position

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a ton of images consisting of a grid of three rows and four columns. There are 14 unique symbols that appear in these twelve cells of grids. How would I train a deep neural network to classify not only the symbol but also its position in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Does each image contain just one of the 14 symbols in one of the 12 cells? If so, you'd just output a one-hot encoding of the symbol as well as a one-hot encoding to represent the cell.

If you need to recognize multiple symbols per image, then you would probably use techniques from object detection. If there is never more than one symbol in a cell, the simplest solution would be to just run the model on each of the 12 patches separately, where it becomes a simple classification problem.

Some relevant concepts/techniques in object detection are: sliding window object detection, R-CNN, bipartite matching.